# How do I trap keyboard input from a Popup control

Tags: wpf, popup, keyboard-events

I am wanting to receive keyboard input from a Popup control that acts as the root visual for a touch screen keyboard control.  I'm wanting the control to support keyboard input as well as touch screen input.  I hook up the events (PreviewKeyDown and KeyDown) and they are never fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Popup` is not focusable by default and even if it is focusable, you have to have something else focusable on the popup and then get it focused or give it the focus in order for it to receive keyboard event.

In other words, if you want keyboard event from the `Popup` use `Focusable="True"` and put a focusable control like a `TextBox` or a `Button` or a `ListBox` and either let the user give it the focus by clicking on it or manually use `Focus()` from code.  If you do all these things then `PreviewKeyDown` should fire for the `Popup`.

Here is a little demonstration program with a toggle button that opens a `Popup` and that shows a slider increasing whenever we get a `PreviewKeyDown` event on a `Popup`:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Slider Name="slider1"/>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton1" 
                      Content="Open Popup"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=toggleButton1}" 
           IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=toggleButton1, Mode=OneWay}" 
           Focusable="True">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewKeyDown">
                <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=slider1}" 
                                         PropertyName="Value" 
                                         Value="1" 
                                         Increment="True"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <TextBox Background="White" 
                 Focusable="True">
            <TextBox.Text>Sample Popup content.</TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Unfortunately given requirements do not allow for a text box. The interface is a touch screen keyboard that needs to respond to keyboard input (i.e. if the user hits the 'E' key that key is hit on the keyboard). The keyboard pops up when the user clicks or touches the text field which otherwise remains read-only (i.e. a TextBlock).

Comment: The demonstration program is just to prove that a popup can receive keyboard input and could use any focusable control besides a textbox.  You didn't say what was on the popup but if they are options of some kind then you could easily make them buttons or a listbox to make them focusable.  There are a hundred ways.

Comment: Yup that works.  Sorry for the misunderstanding.  Turns out I could use something as simple as a TextBlock.  Worked great.

Comment: `i:` is usually used for the blend interactivity namespace. what's `ei:` ? (typo, or some other namespace?)